# Remove all trace of old GRUB that is failing a new 18.10 install

Tags: grub2

I'd like a new install Ubuntu 18.10 to remove a previous (16.04) GRUB presence as it is failing the 18.10 install. The PC is a dual boot with Windows 10, the 16.04 has been deleted by deleting the partition from Win10. I cannot get into Windows 10. I need to remove the old GRUB. I have tried to boot-repair from DVD running 18.10 and that has failed.

Comment: Please provide a link to your boot-info-summary created by boot-repair.

Comment: You need to learn about UEFI mode (default Windows 8/10 installation mode), how to access UEFI settings (in lieu of the old BIOS) and change the boot options there. Regardless of the now missing Ubuntu mentioned there you can **always** boot Windows directly, no "Boot Repair" or similar tools needed.